# Group an array by its first letter - using groupBy method (Lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I would like to group an array according to its first letter (alphabetically) so the output looks something like this:

```
const words = ['Apple', 'Ape', 'Banana', 'Bag', 'Crab', 'Cupboard', 'Dog', 'Dare'];

[
   { 'A' : [ 'Apple', 'Ape' ] },
   { 'B': [ 'Banana', 'Bag' ] },
   { 'C': [ 'Crab', 'Cupboard' ] },
   { 'D': [ 'Dog', 'Dare' ] }
]
```

How would I do this using the groupBy Lodash method? Also in such a way that it could extend to all letters of the alphabet if needed? Would you also use the forEach Lodash method as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have to use lodash, reduce is all you need.

Comment: Lodash would be preferred, but happy to accept reduce() as well

Comment: You don't ned `Object.values()`.

Comment: @Tvde1 To get the arrays in the OPs output I do. It is not just one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lodash you can use multiple methods to get it.

```js
const words = ['Apple', 'Ape', 'Banana', 'Bag', 'Crab', 'Cupboard', 'Dog', 'Dare'];

const grouped = _.map(_.entries(_.groupBy(words, _.first)), ([k,v]) => ({[k]:v}))

console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With plain old JavaScript:

```js
const words = ['Apple', 'Ape', 'Banana', 'Bag', 'Crab', 'Cupboard', 'Dog', 'Dare'];

const grouped = Object.values(words.reduce((acc,word) => (acc[word[0]] ??= {[word[0]]: []}, acc[word[0]][word[0]].push(word), acc), {}))

console.log(grouped);
```